# Is it possible to get the server's CPU core count through a website of it?

Tags: cpu, http

Is it possible to get the server's CPU core count through a website of it?

the demo site: ( a website )

could I get the CPU cores count of it? if I only know the domain which is on the server.

My suppose is use this way `browser -> webserver(eg. nginx) -> CPU core(process)`. to  send HTTP request synchronously and get the return time. is it possible to speculate the CPU cores count through the requests response duration?

Comment: If the physical server is only service one web site that is rarely used by other users then may be. But if it resides on a virtual server sharing one CPU with multiple other sites then the chance is low.

Comment: In this day and age there may be a whole server farm serving this, and hundreds of thousands of other websites, without permanently assigning any of the servers to a particular website. What problem are you trying to solve by checking the core count?

Comment: You cannot determine the number of cores from a website if you know the domain - especially based on the speed of a response.  There are so many levels of complexity and variable factors coming from numerous sources, that this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: " to send HTTP request synchronously and get the return time." - This will tell you nothing about the specifications of the server responding to the request.  There is no way to determine the specifications of a server as a client.  What problem are you attempting to solve exactly?

Answer (score 3):

As of today, most websites are no longer hosted by the owners themselves, instead there are massive server farms managed by companies like Cloudflare or other providers. This way, managing a website from a company PC for example feels still very easy and like before, but in fact you only see an interface provided by your chosen service provider. Doing so is most likely much cheaper than hosting it yourself because on a single server there are multiple websites, which share the given hardware. Like that, if a website does not need high capacities at the moment because there are less requests than usual, the spare capacities can be given to the other websites in order to make them faster/more reliable.

The other way around, if your website needs to handle more requests than usual, it profits from the unused hardware of the other sites. In reality this is of cause much more complicated as different services are probably run inside of containers or other solutions, but I think you get the idea.

The other reason for outsourced hosting is the reliability. External companies are less likely to have big problems, as they have more people trained on solving them, and if they don't they simply lose customers.

Conclusion: any given website you would like to check, which is probably not your own, otherwise you would just look into the control panel, is probably hosted on a big server with several other websites, and they share the RAM, the core and so on. If you don't exactly know that the other websites do nothing at the moment you want to test, it is merely impossible to get the number of cores handling your request(s).

Comment: This is more or less correct, but very oversimplified.  There is a *lot* more going on behind the scenes.  Virtualization, caches, CDNs, multiple hosts, and so much more.

Comment: @Keltari of cause it is. But for the sake of this answer, it is enough. If you want to write a better answer, I will vote for it.

Comment: No its perfectly fine.  I just wanted to point out that it is just a small window in to the question.  I work for one of the largest web hosting companies in the world.  I could spend hours writing an answer.  I dont want to.  Your answer is good enough.  :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get the server's CPU core count through a website of it?

It is possible if and only if the owner of the server has configured a website that tells you the core count.